# Free charting control with date axis

Tags: php, javascript, flash, web-applications

Is there a free web control (serverside php or clientside flash or javascript) that can take a set of datapoints with timestamps (possibly with gaps or at irregular intervals) and draw a chart that would automatically scale the date axis?

If there are a few datapoints hours apart then the chart would draw each datapoint. If there are thousands that span a year, it would draw month grid. If there are gaps - it would interpolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are tons of them. The one that I have experience with (sure to work) is http://code.google.com/p/flot/

See its examples http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/

Specifically, http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html

You just have to mention the timestamp (in ms) for the data points and it will scale based on the data.